# How to create an output that is grouped by consecutive rows? ie: [2002, 2003, 2004] [2006, 2007], [2011], [2013, 2014]

Tags: python, pandas

This is a small segment of the dataframe I'm working with

```
data = {
    'country_name' : ['Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania'],
    'year' : [2017, 2018, 2019, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2007, 2009, 2010],
    'score' : [2.6617181301116943, 2.694303274154663, 2.375091791152954, 2.4360344409942627, 1.2812711000442505, 1.8589999675750732, 4.634251594543457, 5.485469818115234, 5.268936634063721]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvJsz.png)

I want to find the difference of scores between a country and x consecutive year(s). If x = 1 then the output should look like this.

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ7xy.png)

So if the same country has a skipped year then the following recorded year will not have a difference available. Countries that have a year that stand alone will also not have a difference.

I also intend to do the same thing with x = 2,3,4 etc

Comment: What is output if `x=2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create groups by consetutive years compare [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and use it for difference by [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
x = 1
df['diff']=df.groupby(['country_name',df['year'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()])['score'].diff(x)

x = 2
df['diff2']=df.groupby(['country_name',df['year'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()])['score'].diff(x)
print(df)
  country_name  year     score      diff     diff2
0  Afghanistan  2017  2.661718       NaN       NaN
1  Afghanistan  2018  2.694303  0.032585       NaN
2  Afghanistan  2019  2.375092 -0.319211 -0.286626
3  Afghanistan  2021  2.436034       NaN       NaN
4  Afghanistan  2022  1.281271 -1.154763       NaN
5  Afghanistan  2023  1.859000  0.577729 -0.577034
6      Albania  2007  4.634252       NaN       NaN
7      Albania  2009  5.485470       NaN       NaN
8      Albania  2010  5.268937 -0.216533       NaN
```